# How to reposition form button in a Django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a Django template that renders a form.  The code is:

```
{% block body %}
    <h3>
        Create Listing
    </h3>
    <table>
        <form action="{%url 'create' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_table }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create Listing" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

Note: I'm using `<table>` to left justify the input boxes (otherwise the form looks messy on the screen).

The blue `Create Listing` button is currently appearing **above** the input boxes.  How do I move this button such that it's positioned **below** the input boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
<table>
    <form action="{%url 'create' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Create Listing" class="btn btn-primary">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

If you want the button to be aligned with labels (instead of input fields) then put it inside the `<th></th>` tags instead.